# Jqgrid paasing a parameter to custom element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am using Jqgrid for displaying and editing information. In one of the column I am using custom element,

```
        editoptions:{custom_element: getcustomElement,
                     custom_value:getCustomValue},
```

How can I pass a parameter to this custom_element function , Like getCustomElement(a) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this [link](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules). It will help you to understand how to pass the parameters to the custom element. Go to the `custom` subtitle, i think it will help.